# How can I have html5 audio continue to play in background in iOS7 from my flex mobile app

Tags: ios, apache-flex, air, flash-builder, html5-audio

I have mobile app I've developed in flash builder 4.6 (flex 4.12 sdk) and I have a stagewebview component which contains HTML5 audio (mp3 retrieved from my web server and streamed / played via the app)... I want to have the ios version of the app CONTINUE to play the mp3 / html5 audio when the user presses the home button on their iphone or opens another app... so that when multitasking, my audio continues to play (where theres no other NEW audio started, for instance).

I have added the following to my manifest but it still doesnt do what Im after.  I used this in another mobile app where I just play audio from the url directly in flash builder (i.e. NOT via webview component) -- but here it seems the webview suspends (Im guessing)...

```
<iPhone>
    <InfoAdditions><![CDATA[
        <key>UIDeviceFamily</key>
        <array>
            <string>1</string>
        </array>
        <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
        <array>
            <string>audio</string>
        </array>
    ]]></InfoAdditions>
    <requestedDisplayResolution>high</requestedDisplayResolution>
</iPhone>
```

Is there a way around this so my audio continues to play?  My test device is an iphone 4 running the latest version of ios7

Comment: No responses so I take this to mean that the stagewebview instance just suspends while app is inactive - so I guess I'll use as3 to stream the mp3 instead of using the HTML5 audio tag.